# How To See User Database On PGAdminIII with Heroku?

Tags: database, postgresql, heroku, pgadmin

I set up PGAdmin III with my Heroku database.

I was wondering how I can see my Users database. I am still building my website so I wanted to test how they are being registered in the database.

However, all I see is tons of databases with strange "d10abc111ldlapsaman"-like names. How do I access my User database?

If PGAdmin III is not the right tool for this - what tool should I get to see my users of my still - in -development Heroku application?

Answer (score 4):

You may have figured out your issue by now, but what you want to do is go to `https://postgres.heroku.com`. Look at your default connection settings for your database. Now, do the following in *pgAdmin III* using these settings:

1. *File -> Add Server*
2. *Name:* anything you want
   *Host:* `ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com`
   *Port:* `5432`
   *Maintenance DB:* `yourdbname` (in your example it would be `d10abc111ldlapsaman`)
   *Username:* `uiuskwljksjdkje` (change to yours)
   *Password:* `sdjfj3#@f333edfs` (change to yours)
3. The other settings can stay at what they initially were.
4. You should no be connected to the server. Expand it and scroll through the long list until you find your database name (the one that you put as *Maintenance DB*).
5. You're done!

Comment: there are almost 5000 databases there, I want to see only my, how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Updating the answer for someone who still needs it, like me:

1. Go to your heroku account and find your database credentials (you should open your app, then postgres on add-ons and finally settings):
   [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKlV2.png)
2. In pgadmin you should right-click on 'servers'-> create -> server and enter your credentials:

- General/Name: the name that pgadmin will show (only for you)
- Connection/Host name: *Host* in credentials
- Connection/Port: *Port* in credentials (probably 5432)
- Connection/Maintenance database: *Database* in credentials
- Connection/Username: *User* in credentials
- Connection/Password: *Password* in credentials (tip: check the box to save it)
- SSL/SSL mode: Require
- Advanced/DB restriction: your database (same as maintenance db) -> this will filter only your db of the many others that will spam if you don't do that.